# won't or shouldn't?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Scenario:
Ramu is always touching others' ears and he cannot resist doing that.

I want to help him out. So I am asking the following question to a doctor. **Is it correct?**

> Doctor, would you give him a suggestion that he shouldn't or won't
>   touch others' ears?

Comment: Its not very clear what you want to say.  Firstly who is Ramu? Is he your baby? How old is he Next, I don't understand why you are asking a doctor?  Are you asking your doctor to suggest ways to stop Ramu from touching people's ears?

Comment: Yes, let Ram be my baby and I request a doctor or anybody to give him a counselling for that. In this case the question with the that clause used in that is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The way you ask is unclear and it isn't correct English.  You can't say "Would you give him a suggestion" since a baby can't understand him. You can have "a suggestion that he won't do it" but that is not what you mean.

You don't want the doctor to suggest that the baby stop touching ears. You want the doctor to give you suggestions on how to stop your baby from touching ears.

You could ask:

> My son keeps touching people's ears. Do you have any suggestions for how I can stop him from doing that?

Comment: I got what I really wanted from your answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on the ✓ symbol